# how to add number of labels and image view in UITableView cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, uilabel

I am trying to add UIlabels and Uimage views in UITableView cell for facebook posts. It might be happen that some images or values are not available for some of Posts. Then I have to check value of message , name ,caption ,picture and many more. But If some posts do not have caption or picture I don't want to create label for that.. Can I do like this if Value is not null then create label or image view other wise don't create label for that particular cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - that's the way to do it.

Comment: In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, right after you define what cell is, do:

if (cell != nill) { cell.title = ....

Comment: hey I have used number of labels in cell..But now How can Set table cell height according to different label's variable text

Comment: Different cells height is terrible UI. A cell height is set using the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath method.